# Comma says "test file died" while zef test . passes

Tags: raku, commaide

In some cases, and I'm not sure why, comma indicates "test file died" while, apparently, all tests have passed and `zef` does not indicate any problem. Happens for instance in [this file](https://github.com/perl6/Documentable/blob/master/t/401-indexes.t) where the only only quirk seems to be that `plan *` is being used.

[image: Comma image capture]

However, while all tests that fail have that in common, it does not seem to be the only reason, since others with the same `plan` do work. Any idea

Comment: Does the behaviour go away when you `plan` a fixed number of tests?

Comment: @Holli, well, it does not seem to happen in that case. But that's not the point, but the fact that zef test and Comma behave in a different way and why.

Comment: I wonder if there is some log that you could look at with the exact message / return value of the failure.

Comment: I agree, not THE point, yet good to know for whoever is going to debug this.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen There's none I can see; it's simply the "Test file died" message in the Comma UI. The Comma "Event Log" just states the fact: `17:47 Tests failed: 2, passed: 297`

Comment: Oddly, `plan *` seems to cause an empty line to the written before any test output, which is curious, and probably not intended, so perhaps there's an issue with Rakudo's `Test` module in that regard.

Comment: @JonathanWorthington do you mean the one between "Processing Type directory" and `1..0` Come to think of it, I seem to remember some discussion about that with LeonT about how prove processed that output...